# Is there a tool for automatic migrations on sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am working on a backend in Node.js / Sequelize for an iPhone application. I am wondering what the best solution is in 2020 to automate migrations in Sequelize.

I am also willing to change ORM if you recommend a better one than Sequelize that supports automatic migrations.

Comment: `to automate migrations in Sequelize.` was does that mean? What is an automatic Migration?

Comment: Hey @madflow, I am thinking something in the lines of makemigrations in Django

Comment: Maybe checkout: https://typeorm.io/#/migrations "TypeORM is able to automatically generate migration files with schema changes you made.!

Answer (score 2):

you can do this By using Synchronizing function of Sequelize

```
await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
console.log("All models were synchronized successfully.");
```

you check out this [Doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html) of sequelize to for more use of `sequelize.sync`

Comment: While that works, I think it’s absolutely unsuited for production. I was hoping for something more similar to makemigrations in Django